# How to map a wrapped value in fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I have this code and I was wondering if I can transform the below `pipe`s into just one `pipe`?

```
const result: TE.TaskEither<DataTransferError, readonly CoinMetadataDto[]> = pipe(
  this.ensureFundsExist(),
  TE.chain((funds) => {
    return pipe(
      funds.map((fund) => {
        return this.coinGeckoAdapter.getCoinMetadata(fund.coinGeckoId);
      }),
      TE.sequenceArray,
    );
  }),
);
```

In other words can I `map` a `TaskEither<E, Data[]>` into a `TaskEither<E, OtherData[]>` in one go?

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more type information? What are the type of `funds`? Alternatively can you provided a reduced version of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Array.prototype.map` (`funds.map`), you can use the curried [`map`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/ReadonlyArray.ts.html#map) from the `ReadonlyArray` fp-ts module. Combine this with [`flow`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#flow) (left-to-right function composition) and you can get rid of the nested `pipe`:

```ts
import * as RA from 'fp-ts/ReadonlyArray'

const result: TE.TaskEither<DataTransferError, readonly CoinMetadataDto[]> = pipe(
  this.ensureFundsExist(),
  TE.chain(
    flow(
      RA.map(fund => this.coinGeckoAdapter.getCoinMetadata(fund.coinGeckoId)),
      TE.sequenceArray
    )
  )
);
```

However, there’s an even better way of doing this using [`traverseArray`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/TaskEither.ts.html#traversearray):

```ts
export declare const traverseArray: <A, B, E>(
  f: (a: A) => TaskEither<E, B>
) => (as: readonly A[]) => TaskEither<E, readonly B[]>
```

`TE.traverseArray(f)` is equivalent to `flow(RA.map(f), TE.sequenceArray)`.

```ts
const result: TE.TaskEither<DataTransferError, readonly CoinMetadataDto[]> = pipe(
  this.ensureFundsExist(),
  TE.chain(
    TE.traverseArray(fund =>
      this.coinGeckoAdapter.getCoinMetadata(fund.coinGeckoId)
    )
  )
);
```

For more information, have a look at the [`Traversable`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Traversable.ts.html) type class.